# Xamarin Forms AppCenter crashes with unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, ios14

I've recently changed my projects to use .NET core 2 and I'm currently re-testing WPF, Android and iOS.

Unfortunately I've also been upgrading my Nugets to get the UWP project working and Xcode was updated this morning too to Version 12.0 (12A7209), followed by Visual Studio for Mac, so I'm not quite sure what to blame as-yet.

I did have problems with App Center not wanting to upgrade from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2, so I resorted to clearing my Nuget cache and editing the project solutions manually, now they're all pointing to 3.4.2 (latest as of 23rd September 2020).

The following error seems to be the root cause, but I don't understand what I need to do to resolve it?

```
NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: +[MSAnalytics sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1eb4f2678
```

Crash Log...

```
2020-09-23 13:16:16.816 MYAPP
.iOS[3555:1395741] +[MSAnalytics sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1eb4f2678
2020-09-23 13:16:19.770 MYAPP
.iOS[3555:1395741] [AppCenterCrashes] ERROR: +[MSWrapperLogger MSWrapperLog:tag:level:]/10 Unhandled Exception:
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: +[MSAnalytics sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1eb4f2678
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d51e5c0 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 1185216
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a159842c objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d42d324 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 197412
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d521130 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 1196336
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d523420 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
    5   MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108af7388 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 78359712
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d4af2a8 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 729768
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d4aed80 CFSortIndexes + 320
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d4017d0 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 18384
    9   MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108af7318 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 78359600
    10  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108af6f10 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 78358568
    11  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108af6e54 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 78358380
    12  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108af5c88 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 78353824
    13  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001081a75b4 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 68595404
    14  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x000000010819617c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 68524692
    15  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001081afeac _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 68630468
    16  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001081b21a4 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 68639420
    17  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000107e174b0 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 64859592
    18  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001071340d8 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 51345904
    19  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000106d7181c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 47403316
    20  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001040ece78 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 722832
    21  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001049af660 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 9908088
    22  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108b671d4 mono_pmip + 28148
    23  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108c23420 mono_pmip + 798784
    24  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108c26c84 mono_pmip + 813220
    25  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x000000010403eba8 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 9408
    26  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x000000010403f39c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 11444
    27  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fe34a68 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 12032616
    28  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fe36ac4 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 12040900
    29  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fe3c478 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 12063864
    30  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4cdd70 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2174320
    31  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fa194d4 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
    32  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4ce8c0 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2177216
    33  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4ce38c 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2175884
    34  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4ce6d0 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2176720
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4cdf48 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2174792
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4d6078 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2207864
    37  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f92bc28 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 6753320
    38  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fa31810 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 272
    39  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f4d5df0 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 2207216
    40  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f30aeb0 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 327344
    41  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f30986c 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 321644
    42  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f30aad8 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 326360
    43  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fe3a668 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 12056168
    44  UIKitCore                           0x000000018f954274 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 6918772
    45  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c4d02dc A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 37596
    46  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c4faa00 A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 211456
    47  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c4ded24 A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 97572
    48  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c4fa6d0 A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 210640
    49  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018d11cac8 8E662F82-B1E4-3E7E-A376-18E9755A8F51 + 15048
    50  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018d120348 8E662F82-B1E4-3E7E-A376-18E9755A8F51 + 29512
    51  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c5220e0 A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 372960
    52  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c521d88 A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 372104
    53  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000019c5222ac A1960BD9-CE29-3E96-817D-955EBEB140BE + 373420
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d49b81c 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 649244
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d49b718 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 648984
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d49aa94 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 645780
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d494d20 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 621856
    58  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d4944bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    59  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001a3f19820 GSEventRunModal + 164
    60  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fe38734 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 12048180
    61  UIKitCore                           0x000000018fe3de10 UIApplicationMain + 168
    62  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000105c6d838 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 29561168
    63  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000105328ef0 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 19843080
    64  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000105328d74 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 19842700
    65  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001040ec0d0 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 719336
    66  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001049af660 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 9908088
    67  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108b671d4 mono_pmip + 28148
    68  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108c23420 mono_pmip + 798784
    69  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108c29678 mono_pmip + 823960
    70  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108b4578c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 78680228
    71  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x0000000108d2fc34 xamarin_localized_string_format_9 + 24676
    72  MYAPP
    .iOS                      0x00000001040ebfd8 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 719088
    73  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018d15be60 90A4E82E-250C-35E3-8B2D-51D6D8B1119B + 3680

  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:407 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:128 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings.MSAppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, ObjCRuntime.Class[] services) [0x00034] in <30815ef5d71a4a61bca2d2557a5ade14>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x0002d] in <556514ba772641f3a49c90b8d313bb6b>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <556514ba772641f3a49c90b8d313bb6b>:0 
  at MYAPP
  .App.OnStart () [0x0003a] in /Users/rob/GitHub/MYCOMPANY-MYAPP
  -appv2/app/MYAPP
  /MYAPP
  /App.xaml.cs:94 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendStart () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:346 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication uiApplication, Foundation.NSDictionary launchOptions) [0x00036] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\FormsApplicationDelegate.cs:58 
  at MYAPP
  .iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0013e] in /Users/rob/GitHub/MYCOMPANY-MYAPP
  -appv2/app/MYAPP
  /MYAPP
  .iOS/AppDelegate.cs:103 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at MYAPP
  .iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/rob/GitHub/MYCOMPANY-MYAPP
  -appv2/app/MYAPP
  /MYAPP
  .iOS/Main.cs:16
```

Version information...

```
=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.7.8 (build 4)
Installation UUID: 48517e8c-1181-4780-9ee3-ffab8aec9534
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

    Package version: 612000093

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.12.0.93 (2020-02/620cf538206) (64-bit)
    Package version: 612000093

=== Roslyn (Language Service) ===

3.7.0-6.20427.1+18ede13943b0bfae1b44ef078b2f3923159bcd32

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.7.0.6702

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.1.402
    3.1.401
    3.1.302
    3.1.301
    3.1.300
    3.1.200
    3.1.102
    3.1.101
    3.0.101
    3.0.100
    2.1.701
    2.1.505
    2.1.504
    2.1.503
    2.1.302
    2.1.4
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.1.8
    3.1.7
    3.1.6
    3.1.5
    3.1.4
    3.1.2
    3.1.1
    3.0.1
    3.0.0
    2.1.22
    2.1.21
    2.1.20
    2.1.19
    2.1.18
    2.1.17
    2.1.16
    2.1.15
    2.1.14
    2.1.13
    2.1.12
    2.1.9
    2.1.8
    2.1.7
    2.1.2
    2.0.5

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

'/Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app' not found

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 12.0 (17219)
Build 12A7209

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 6.20.2.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 817b6f72a
Branch: d16-7
Build date: 2020-07-18 18:44:59-0400

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 14.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 7ec3751a1
Branch: xcode12
Build date: 2020-09-16 11:33:15-0400

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.7.0.495
Hash: 03d50a221
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7-vsmac
Build date: 2020-08-28 13:12:52 UTC

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 11.0.2.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-7/025fde9
Android SDK: /Users/rob/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)
        7.1 (API level 25)
        8.0 (API level 26)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.6
SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: 83105ba
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-7@1f3388a
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-7@017078f

=== Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile ===

Java SDK: /Users/rob/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 16.7.0.13
Hash: 8380518
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7~2
Build date: 2020-09-16 05:12:24 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 16.7.0.24
Hash: bb090a3
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7
Build date: 2020-09-16 05:12:46 UTC

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 807080004
Git revision: 9ea7bef96d65cdc3f4288014a799026ccb1993bc
Build date: 2020-09-16 17:22:54-04
Build branch: release-8.7
Xamarin extensions: 9ea7bef96d65cdc3f4288014a799026ccb1993bc

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.15.6
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0
    Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020
    root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Based on your error message, please  open up xcode. If it prompted you to install some additional tools like this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413921/what-causes-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class-error-on-xamarin-forms-build

Comment: Thanks @LeonLu-MSFT that was the first thing that I checked but I had installed the components prior to launching Visual Studio, but I double-checked anyway and there's no prompt to install additional tools.

Comment: Can your roll back your Nugets packages?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT unfortunately when getting the UWP project up and working I decided to upgrade the projects to .netcore (seemed like a good idea at the time), so I can't rollback because some nugets are not compatible with .netcore.  I can probably rollback just the AppCenter nugets though - that sounds like a good place to start, thanks for the idea.

Comment: I make the same experience as @Devology Ltd with an existing project. I don't have a solution but after downgrading the Xamarin.iOS SDK from 14.0.0.0 to 13.20.2.2 [link] (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios) the exception was not thrown anymore so it could be related to the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was because of class name conflict with some Apple private framework. Apple added `MSAnalytics` class in iOS 14, so it conflicts with App Center SDK.

[3.4.3](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/3.4.3) with a hotfix for this issue has been released. In this patch, `MSAnalytics` is renamed to `MSACAnalytics` to avoid this conflict.

Related GutHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/issues/1445/

Comment: Just tested with 3.4.3 and it's resolved, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Thank so much for your help. Very much appreciated!